# Highlighting words in text file using HTML

Tags: html

I have a text file which is not cleaned or pre-processed. It contains lots of unnecessary words. I want to highlight those words show it in UI (user interface) and then remove the junk and show cleaned text.

My approach:

- I am putting junk sentence/words in < mark > This is uncleaned text < /mark> tag. - Then passing it to UI using HTML.
- The source output that I am getting is:

Current Output:

```
mark& gt;This is uncleaned text;/mark&gt
```

Expected Output:

```
This is uncleaned text should be highlighted.
```

Comment: Someone edited and <mark> </mark>? is not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlight text with only HTML code. To highlight text with just HTML code and support for all browsers, set the background-color style, as shown in the example below, using the `<span>` HTML tag. In the above example, the `<span>` HTML tag has a background-color code of #FFFF00, which is Yellow.

Comment: Cannot find the example.

Comment: I cannot see the example either. Also, please learn about formatting helpfully, to avoid parts of your answer staying invisible in the rendering of your post: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help You are aware that you can [edit] your posts, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```css
mark {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<p><mark>This is uncleaned text</mark> and should be highlighted.</p>
```

`Mark` Element Documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_mark.asp